# Google Apps Script: Is there a directory of available libraries and their Script IDs?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a directory of available libraries and their Script IDs for use with Google Apps Script?

Thank you.

I've looked everywhere, but I can find no resources for Script IDs. I've tried a couple script IDs, but they didn't work. And I have not found any online resources that discus using script IDs or library extensions for programming on Google Apps Script.

Comment: I don't think there is anything official, but there is [this](https://github.com/tanaikech/Google-Apps-Script-Library-Database/blob/master/Google-Apps-Script-Library-Database.json)

Comment: Thank you, Miguel! I'll spend some time with this...